# What's that hard scifi novel I read about exploiting the discovery of a wormhole?

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi, wormhole

The book details the history of a man who discovers a pinpoint wormhole in space, and slowly he learns to harness its power to succeed in life.

To jog your memory:

- It starts with a guy at an overlook, making out with his girlfriend.  Maybe overlooking a rocket field.  He makes a lofty promise to her (maybe that he'll own all of this one day?).  Eventually they get married and become fabulously wealthy, thanks to the discovery of the wormhole.
- It ends with him and his wife repeatedly stepping through one end of the wormhole in his business empire's vault, emerging out the other end later in time.  A valet then walks them across the room to the entrance to the wormhole, to repeat the process.  Thus they jump forward in time until science knows how to make them immortal.
- It features him meeting 2 other versions of himself -- one with a moustache, one with a beard.
- At one point, an enemy ship is hurtling toward our ship, but our ship has the wormholes on either side of it.  The enemy ship is deflected off course and into wormhole 1, by a damaged ship flying out of wormhole 2 -- the same ship, sent a few seconds into the past.

What's the name of this book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The novel is [*Timemaster*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/263465.Timemaster) by Robert L. Forward.  The wormhole discovered is actually a negmatter creature that lives in space called a Silverhair.  The Silverhair and the negmatter balls it excretes are used as the basis for wormholes, reactionless drives and ultimately, time machines.

Comment: Thanks so much!  After reading the negative Amazon reviews, I wonder if this book will be as good to re-read now that I'm older... :)

Comment: The characters are lacking in subtlety, but Forward was a first-rate engineer and scientist; it is that agile mind at play that makes reading his sf such a pleasure for me.

Comment: Sadly, IMO, this book was terrible.  BUT!  The wormhole ship trap (described by the OP) is interesting - see [this Wikipedia article on the "Novikov self-consistency principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle) which mentions that author Robert Forward and Kip Thorne did some of the analysis of this CTC scenario.

Comment: @davidbak I suspect the awkward characterization and melodrama could be easily missed by a science minded adolescent reader.  If the book wasn't targeted to such an audience it should have been.  It's certainly no worse than Heinlein in this regard.

Comment: "no worse than Heinlein" - uhh, I guess we'll have to disagree there ... for this book.

Comment: @davidbak Compare Forward's characters to those in Heinlein's "Waldo" for instance.  Like Forward, Heinlein would spin up caricatures as vehicles for his current pet theory or notion.  Heinlein's default character position was orneriness, Forward's was bombastic optimism.  Neither of them were Hemingway.